# How to chain Q deferred promises in nested loop with Firebase DB async callbacks

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, q, google-cloud-functions

Note: I know there are multiple *similar* answered questions out there already, I read them, but I am still having difficulties with my scenario.

I have a (Google) Firebase Cloud Function that needs to run many queries, in a certain order, also in a loop. Something like this for example (using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) and [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)):

```
let users = [foo, bar, baz, qux, etc, ...];
let myPromises = [];

_.each(users, function (user) {

    // Query A (async)
    let queryA = function() {
        let deferred = Q.defer();
        let _queryA = function() {
            admin.database().ref('blah').child(blah).once("value", function(snapshot) {
                // logic
                return deferred.resolve();
            });
        };
        _queryA();
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    // Query B (async)
    let queryB = function() {
        let deferred = Q.defer();
        let _queryB = function() {
            admin.database().ref('blah').child(blah).once("value", function(snapshot) {
                // logic
                return deferred.resolve();
            });
        };
        _queryB();
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    // Query C (async) with nested (async) query loop
    let queryC = function() {
        let deferred = Q.defer();
        let _queryC = function() {
            admin.database().ref('blah').child(blah).once("value", function(snapshot) {
                // logic

                let potatoPromises = [];

                // another query loop
                _.each(snapshot.val(), function (potato) {
                    let potato_deferred = Q.defer();
                    admin.database().ref('blah').child(potato.id).once("value", function(potato_snapshot) {
                        // logic

                        return potato_deferred.resolve();
                    });
                    potatoPromises.push(potato_deferred.promise);
                });

                Q.all(potatoPromises).then(function() { return deferred.resolve() });
            });
        };
        _queryC();
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    // Function D (sync)
    let functionD() = function() {
        let deferred = Q.defer();
        let _functionD = function() {
            // logic
        });
        _functionD();
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    myPromises.push(Q.all([queryA(),queryB()]).then(queryC()).then(functionD()));

});

Q.all(myPromises).then(function() {
    // Final logic ran only once after all promises in loop are resolved
});
```

For each user iterated through, `queryC` must wait to start until both `queryA` and `queryB` (which can run in any order, hence the `Q.all()`) are finished, and `functionD` must wait until `queryC` is finished.

I *thought* the code above would do the trick, but when I run the Cloud Function, `queryA`, `queryB`, `queryC`, and `functionD` are all immediately starting.

The only Promise that *is* working for me is the final logic ran once at the very end, which *is* waiting for `queryA`, `queryB`, `queryC`, and `functionD` before starting like I want it to- but the logic inside of that final function uses information determined for each `user` in `queryC` and `functionD` so it does not work properly anyway.

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: `.then(queryC())` immediately invokes `queryC` ... you want `.then(queryC)` ... etc - note: any `.then` argument should be a function, not the result of calling a function - (of course if the called function returns a function that's quite fine, but your functions don't return a function)

Comment: in summary - myPromises.push(Q.all([queryA(),queryB()]).then(queryC).then(functionD))` is closer to what you intended - though, I'm sure the code can be greatly simplified, as I'm sure `firebase` methods already return a Promise anyway

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a try now.
As for the Firebase query promises, I think you're right. I just now read https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html and it shows how I can use them.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not using native promises? Are you forced to use shims?

Comment: Not really, no. The only (bad) reason is that I am in a hurry to get this project done and knew more about Q deferreds than native promises. In the long term I would've gone back and replaced them but for the short term that was my "solution"

Comment: quick and untested (obviously) rewrite - https://jsfiddle.net/h5r9v0b9/

Comment: one thing I noticed in your code ... `let queryA = () {` ... that's not valid javascript - should all such code be `let queryA = () => {` or `let queryA = function() {` perhaps?

Comment: Yes, that's my bad, they're anonymous functions in my code but I guess I missed that in the question. I'm editing my question now.

Comment: It's all good, I guessed what you meant I think

Comment: yes that looks about right (I didn't notice the `//logic` in your question :p )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, you are invoking C and D:

```
myPromises.push(Q.all([queryA(),queryB()]).then(queryC).then(functionD));
```